# Failed to initialize editor. when update android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

today i have update my android studio version **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1** then i got an issue.

like xml preview are not showing.

and suggestion not found in `xml` and `java` class

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LCfp.png)

Comment: This is happening to most of us. Android Studio update functionality is quite buggy try to completely uninstall current android studio then download and install new version again instead of update.

Comment: I have also tried, like invalid cache and restart and fully uninstall android studio. but same issue found.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrard your project into `build.gradle [app level]`
Change your targetSdk and compileSdk `33` to `32`, and downgrade your library...

Change minSdk atleast `21`

```
android{

    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
       minSdk 21
       targetSdk 32
       ...
    }
...
}
```

And

Use this versions of librarys ...

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade to latest AGP version, you can do it manually or using upgrade assistant as shown below. You can find in view->tools->upgrade assistant.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

On clicking on run selecting steps, it will start upgrading to latest AGP.

**Final Step**

Sync gradle

if it doesn't work you need to reopen your project or restart android studio.