# How can fix the failed to initialize editor in android java

Tags: java, android, xml

After android dolphin apdate xml is dosen't work properly

I found that problem - failed to initialize editor or layout preview dosn't show

i tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782792/failed-to-initialize-editor-when-update-android-studio/73784494#73784494) , but it dosn't work properly

example - [image]

Comment: Did you try "File->Invalidate Caches-> Invalidate and restart"?

Comment: yes , i do But that didn't work either

Comment: Check my answer here [Fixed initialize editor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782792/failed-to-initialize-editor-when-update-android-studio/74037789#74037789)

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Cache -> Restart

Sync Gradle/Clean Build

Comment: That didn't work